# fonts on org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite are messed up on Linux

Tags: java, linux, fonts, eclipse-plugin, swt

I  extend org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite and create many widgets on it, (labels, table, text etc). The problem I am facing is that the labels' text is getting truncated on linux while it appears fine on windows. When I change the linux's font to gothic the truncation is little less but still there. Is there way to  homogenize the windows and linux display. What could be the best font to use in linux in such a case.

Answer (score 1):

More likely it is related to this eclipse bug which I just lobbied to have re-opened: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=151322

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using absolute positioning instead of [dynamic layouts](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html). *(If this isn't the case, perhaps you could post code demonstrating the problem).* Using a dynamic layout should ensure that controls are resized to accommodate their contents. *(They're also great if you ever translate a product, because then you don't have to rejig every dialog for every language.)*

Answer (score 0):

To complete McDowel's answer, there is also a **[bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=192365&x=0&y=0&query_format=specific&order=relevance+desc&bug_status=__open__)** related to the way Linux check for wrapping label:

[image]

It is fixed since 3.4M7.

Even though it may not be related to your case, it would be useful to know which version of eclipse you are using and if you can reproduce your bug with the latest ones (like a 3.5M6)